# How to reshape dataframe to a [colName, rowName, value] format?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following dataframe:

```
          Akron   Baltimore   Detroit
Boston    542     2040        367
Chicago   1670    1215        4636
Dallas    740     388         491
```

I need to display this dataframe in a [colName, rowName, value] format such as:

```
Akron     Boston   542
Akron     Chicago  1670
Akron     Dallas   740
Baltimore Boston   2040
Baltimore Chicago  1215
Baltimore Dallas   388
Detroit   Boston   367
Detroit   Chicago  4636
Detroit   Dallas   491
```

I tried using `df.melt()` but this gave me:

```
0    Akron     542
1    Akron     1670
2    Akron     740
3    Baltimore 2040
4    Baltimore 1215
5    Baltimore 388
6    Detroit   367
7    Detroit   4636
8    Detroit   491
```

How can I reshape my data to get the desired result?

Comment: use `df.stack()`

Comment: `df.reset_index().melt('index')`

Comment: Use `df.stack().reset_index()`

Comment: `df.stack().reset_index()` is the only solution here which gives the appropriate format, however the first and second columns are switched, but I can fix that issue very easily

Comment: update: `df.unstack().reset_index()` gives me the correct layout and column order